# Best way to delete contents from DynamoDB Table (Using Jenkins + CloudFormation)

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I have a Cloudformation template that creates a DynamoDB table.

Within that same Jenkins pipeline, I have a pipeline script that has multiple stages.  For one of those stages, I actually deploy this same CloudFormation template.  What I tried to do in Jenkins was make 1 stage that deletes the DynamoDB table:

```
   stage('Delete DynamoDB Table'){
        sh "aws dynamodb delete-table --table-name ThisTable --region us-east-1"
    }
```

Then I deploy the CFT

```
   stage('Deploy CloudFormation Template'){
```

And then I upload data into DynamoDB

```
   stage('Upload Data to Dynamo'){
```

My problem is, when I delete the DynamoDB table outright, my Deploy CFT stage cannot run because it does not like that.  So the Jenkins pipeline actually fails before I reach the the upload stage.

Does anyone know of a better way to delete items from DynamoDB?  I was told that you could not truncate a DynamoDB table and the best way was to just drop the table and recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

delete-table doesn't delete the table automatically, but only initiates the delete operations, which will be carried on by AWS. You should use describe-table to check if the table was deleted before moving to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CloudFormation then you should be cautious deleting the table, since other things may be dependent on its existence. 
My solution would be to delete all row in that table. Following code will delete all rows in the table:

```
 public async Task DeleteAllReadModelEntitiesInTable()
{
    List<ReadModelEntity> readModels;

    var conditions = new List<ScanCondition>();
    readModels = await _context.ScanAsync<ReadModelEntity>(conditions).GetRemainingAsync();

    var batchWork = _context.CreateBatchWrite<ReadModelEntity>();
    batchWork.AddDeleteItems(readModels);
    await batchWork.ExecuteAsync();
}
```